# Tibco EMS protocol

Tags: node.js, message-queue, tibco-ems

I am trying to interface with a Tibco EMS server using node.js and am curious if this is possible using entirely open source solutions solely in node.js. I do not want to use Tibco's Web Messaging solution.

So then this brings us to... does Tibco EMS speak any standard protocol like AMQP? Could I talk to it over a raw tcp socket? I have thought about setting up a Java service to simply handle message routing but ideally I would like the entire solution to be in node.js. I just need to be able to connect to different Queues and enqueue/dequeue messages. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TIBCO EMS supports the JMS standard through its drivers for various platforms. For node i would say the most straight forward way would be to use it's C drivers and build a node module to connect.

Cheers
       Sebastian

Comment: I ended up just making a Java REST service to handle message routing so other services could just talk to the Java service, although this is also a good solution.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate on what you mean by C drivers please? I'm also looking for a way to connect a node js application to EMS.  Any code samples would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: @HuzanToorkey here's one example lib I am aware of: https://github.com/JensWalter/node-ems, have a look at the samples